# Extracting recurring elements from array (Bad Value for Range Error)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to extract/grab all elements between the tags ":desc:" and ":/desc" from this array

```
array = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc:",
         ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc:"]
```

so that I have

```
new_array = [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc:"],
             [":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc:"]]
```

I tried

```
final_array = []

start_element = ':desc:'
end_element = ':/desc:'

while array.any?
  final_array << array.slice!
(array.find_index(start_element)..array.find_index(end_element))
end
```

But it is obviously not working because I get a `bad value for range` error.

Comment: Could it be a typo? Array elements are `":/desc"` but you have `end_element = ":/desc:"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. From your example array it looks like the ending element is `':/desc'` rather than `':/desc:'` (i.e. no trailing `:`). That could just be a typo in the question though.

The main issue is that after removing the 2 slices the array will not be empty (it will still contain the `"hello"` from before the first `start_element`. This means that the `array.any?` condition will still be true when `find_index(start_element)` isn't going to find a matching element. In this case `find_index` will return `nil`, leading to a `no implicit conversion from nil to integer` when trying to use `slice!`.

If you know that your data will always contain `start_element` and `end_element` in matched pairs then one approach would be:

```
while start_index = array.find_index(start_element)
  end_index = array.find_index(end_element)
  final_array << array.slice!(start_index..end_index)
end
```

---

When faced with this kind of error in the future, some trusty `puts` debugging will help, in this case checking the 2 indexes and the remaining contents of the array:

```
while array.any?
  start_index = array.find_index(start_element)
  end_index = array.find_index(end_element)
  puts "#{start_index}..#{end_index}"
  final_array << array.slice!(start_index..end_index)
  puts array.inspect
end

1..5
["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc"]
1..6
["hello"]
..
TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
from (pry):146:in `slice!'
```

Comment: thanks @mikej yep its pretty good actually and working perfectly with ruby. But when implemented on Rails (in the controller) it does'nt. Rails throws an "undefined method `find_index'". Any idea ? I am correctly calling the array and inputing the start and end element. The debugger show this line of code as a problem :     while start_index = array.find_index(start_element)
Any input on this ?

Comment: If there's no `find_index` method on the object then it sounds like you don't actually have an array. Where is the data coming from? Is it being submitted in params? Can you add your controller code to the end of the question or alternatively post a new question with it?

Answer (score 2):

You also can use combination of [`Enumarable#slice_after`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after) and [`Enumarable#drop_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while):

```
array.slice_after(':/desc').map { |e| e.drop_while { |i| i != ':desc:' } }
#=> [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"],
#    [":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc"]]
```

Comment: This assumes the array has a particular structure. What if `arr = [':/desc', ':desc', '/:desc']` or `[':desc:'. ':/desc', 'bob', ':desc:', ':/desc']`.

Comment: @ilya this returns  that : #<NoMethodError: undefined method `slice_after' for #<String:0x007fd4f3eb6908>> on rails any idea why ?

Comment: @Goeast Are you using Ruby 2.3 or later?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that subarrays beginning with `":desc:"`and ending with `":/desc"`, and containing no other instances of `":/desc"`, are to be extracted. Note that if `arr = [":desc:", ":desc:", ":/desc"]`, `[a]` is returned. I've made no assumptions about the structure of the array (but I've not tested all possibilities). If certain assumptions are made (the existence of matched, non-overlapping pairs, for example, simplifications are possible.

**Code**

```
def extract(arr, target_start, target_end)
  arr.select { |s| (s == target_start)..(s == target_end) ? true : false }.
      slice_when { |s,t| [s, t] == [target_end, target_start] }.
      to_a.
      tap { |a| a.pop unless a.last.last == target_end }
end
```

**Examples**

```
target_start = ":desc:"
target_end = ":/desc"

arr = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc",
       ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc"]
extract(arr, target_start, target_end)
  #=> [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"],
  #    [":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc"]]

arr = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc", "wanda",
       ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc", "herb"]
extract(arr, target_start, target_end)
  # => [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"],
  #     [":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test", ":/desc"]]

arr = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc",
       ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test"]
extract(arr, target_start, target_end)
  #=> [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"]]

arr = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":desc:", "claire",
        "caca", "concise", "test"]
extract(arr, target_start, target_end)
  #=> []
```

**Explanation**

Consider

```
arr = ["hello", ":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc",
       ":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test"]
```

and `target_start` and `target_end` as given in the example. The steps are as follows.

```
b = arr.select { |s| (s == target_start)..(s == target_end) ? true : false }
  #=> [":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc", ":desc:", "claire",
  #    "caca", "concise", "test"]
```

This first step, which makes use of Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/), returns an array that contains all elements of `arr` except those the precede the first `":desc:"` and those that are between between each `":/desc"` and the first `":desc:"` that follows.

Next we use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (new in Ruby v2.2) to produce an enumerator that slices `b` as desired, and then convert that enumerator to an array.

```
c = b.slice_when { |s,t| [s, t] == [target_end, target_start] }
   #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000001dd4f18>:each>
d = c.to_a
   #=> [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"],
   #    [":desc:", "claire", "caca", "concise", "test"]]
```

The last step is remove the last array of `d` if it does not terminate with `":/desc"`, which is the case here. We can use [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) for that, but not directly as it returns the popped element, which would cause the method to return that value as well. If, however, we use it in a [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) block, all is well.

```
d.tap { |a| a.pop unless a.last.last == target_end }
  #=> [[":desc:", "claire", "et", "concise", ":/desc"]]
```